# App bar covers fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I'm building an android app with the navigation drawer template. I've got a class named MainActivity with a layout that includes my **app_bar_main.xml**, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.erik.fuelbuddy.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" >

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_container** will be used to display fragments. Here's one of them as an example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.erik.fuelbuddy.NearbyFragment"
>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nearby" />

</FrameLayout>
```

However, the **TextView** is displayed underneath the ToolBar, which can be confirmed by adding a padding to it, for instance 100dp.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding this line:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to the container FrameLayout like so:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a layout in between add the content

Mean you directly show the toolbar that is the toolbar directly contain the full content view layout so you should be take a layout in between you take the your toolbar and Container.

Show the Layout you want like this But take in layout for show the contentview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.erik.fuelbuddy.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" >

</FrameLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</LinearLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just met the issue, try this:
delete this line android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from your main layout container, in your case layapp_bar_main.xml, it works for me